# iOS 7 & Scroll Bar Colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scrollbar

I have seen posts on changing the color of a scroll bar in iOS.

> UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault:
>
> The default style of scroll indicator, which is black with a white border. This style is good against any content background.
>
> UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack:
>
> A style of indicator which is black and smaller than the default style. This style is good against a white content background.
>
> UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite:
>
> A style of indicator is white and smaller than the default style. This style is good against a black content background.

I am wondering if iOS 7 introduces any new way to change the scroll bar to a UI Color?

Thanks.

Comment: iOS 7 is still under NDA. Ask this in the Apple developer forums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the final iOS 7 SDK it is possible with the constants you suggested. Just set it like

```
tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;
```

Answer (score 0):

No there are no way to change the scroll bar color in iOS 7. However, you can subclass the UIScrollView class and create your own scroll view that may have different UI colors.